# Too many errors emitted in 3rd party libraries on Xcode 6.2

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, backendless

I have installed cocoapods for the first time on mac os x 10.9.6 with xcode 6.2.
When I open xcworkspace, it gives out a lot of parse issues:

[image: Screenshot]

This problem is not only with this library but with AFNetworking too.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightweight generics were introduced in Xcode 7.

You'll need to upgrade to a more recent Xcode if you want to build Objective C code that includes them.